# Why does MemoryStream.Length (or byte[].Length) differs from HttpPostedFile.ContentLength in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, stream, memorystream

I have a base64 encoded image that I need to send to some server. What I do:

```
string content = (string) someDynamicObjectFromJson;
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(content); 
var actualImage = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
long contentLength = imageBytes.Length; // or actualImage.Length
```

For some image I get `content length` equals to `25`.

But when I upload the same image from html form and define controller action with `HttpPostedFileBase` param I get `content length` equals to '53219':

```
public virtual ActionResult UploadPartyImages(HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
    long contentLength = image.ContentLength; // equals to '34451'
}
```

And in `HttpPostedFileBase` I can assign this `contentLength` to `HttpWebRequest.ContenLength`:

```
request.ContentLength = contentLength;
```

And the image will be uploaded to the server. In case of assigning MemoryStream.Length I get:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established
>   connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

**What MSDN says:**

1) HttpPostedFile.ContentLength - Gets the length of the stream in bytes.
2) MemoryStream.Length - Gets the length of the stream in bytes.

**Qustions:**

1) If the descriptions are the same why am I getting so different values (25 and 53219)?
2) What is the proper way to get `ContentLength` from MemoryStream (or base64 image rather) so that I can set Content-Length http header?

**Edits:**
I've read that I can save the file and then create `FileInfo` instance. And call Length property. But I think it is not a proper way to handle such things.

Comment: The base64 string does not contain the same image/bytes as the form upload as it seems. Also 25 bytes is very small for an image.

Comment: You should not assign HttpWebRequest.ContentLength because the content length is not the length of your image. It is the length of the form encoded bytes of the HTTP protocol. Use GetRequestStream. Actually, it is even more complex than that. Use Fiddler to see what a properly formatted <form> POST with a file input looks like.